# Unable to add json key values in array why in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

My json contains image, type and id.. here i want my ids in separate individual array called idArray.. here i am able to get single id in log, i have append ids to idArray but i am not getting ids in array it shows nil why?

i have taken idArray as string. please help me in code.

here is my json structure:

```
{
"financer": [
{
    "id": "45",
    "icon": "https://hello.com//images/img1.png"
     "tpe": "bank"
}
{
    "id": "40",
    "icon": "https://hello.com//images/img2.png"
     "tpe": "wallet"
 }
 .
 .
 .
]
}
```

here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
struct JsonData {

var iconHome: String?
var typeName: String?
init(icon: String, tpe: String) {
    self.iconHome = icon
    self.typeName = tpe
}
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var itemsArray = [JsonData]()
var idArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeServiceCall()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.typeName
    cell.paymentImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:aData.iconHome!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "GVMC_icon"))

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymentViewController") as? MakePaymentViewController
    {
        nextViewController.financerId = idArray[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }
    else{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "will update soon..", in: self)
    }
}
//MARK:- Service-call

func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://webservices/getfinancer"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{

            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            //print("the home json is \(jsonObj)")
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]
            print("home financerData \(financerArray)")

            for financer in financerArray {

                let id = financer["id"] as? String
                let pic = financer["icon"] as? String
                let typeName = financer["tpe"] as! String
                print("home financer id \(String(describing: id))")
                self.idArray.append(id ?? "")
                print("the home financer idsArray \(self.idArray.append(id ?? ""))")

                self.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic ?? "", tpe: typeName))
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }

    }).resume()
}
}
```

Unable to json ids in separate array please help me in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use multiple arrays as data source. That's very bad practice.

Create two structs conforming to `Decodable`

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let financer : [Financer]
}

enum Type : String, Decodable {
    case bank, wallet
}

struct Financer : Decodable {
    let id : String
    let icon : URL
    let tpe : Type
}
```

Declare the data source array

```
var itemsArray = [Financer]()
```

and delete

```
var idArray = [String]()
```

Replace `homeServiceCall` with

```
func homeServiceCall() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://dev.com/webservices/getfinancer")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }

        do {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            }
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:  data!)
            self.itemsArray = result.financer
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error) -- print always the error instance.
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

In `cellForRow` get the `id` value with

```
let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.id
```

**Important note:**

Never never ever use synchronous `Data(contentsOf` to load data from a remote URL. Use an API which loads the data **a**synchronously and caches the images

Comment: thank you, but i need ids in separate array because by using idsarray i need to push different viewcontrollers in didselectIteam at index path

Comment: No you don't, get the id from the item in the array like in `cellForRow`

Comment: i have deleted that question and i have updated this question.. if i didn't take separate id array then how can i push different viewcontollers in didselectIteam

Comment: financerId in didselect is for different view controllers depend on different viewcontroller the financerId will change..

Comment: In `didSelectItem` replace `nextViewController.financerId = idArray[indexPath.row]` with `nextViewController.financerId = itemsArray[indexPath.row].id`. This passes the `id` for the selected index path

Comment: thank you soo much bro for this peace of code i have posted one more question.. i have tried its working.